Elevation Profile result is a flat line - QGIS
I have a solid data set composed of DEM's and point clouds, both of which were capable of creating contours. However, when trying to cut a profile section, I just get a flat line.
I've verified that the CRS is the same for all inputs...
Point Cloud View:

Topo View:

Workspace image:


I can't see a raster elevation layer. I don't think the elevation tool will work from a point cloud. You will likely have to convert it into a raster first.

Copy that - thank you!

So weird - I cannot get this to work. Made sure to reference a rasterized layer and nothing...still flat. Any ideas?

Are you sure that is a DEM? Because the picture you posted is just a map with contour lines.
